# powershell 3.0 "get-disk" missing

Tags: powershell

I have Windows 8 Enterprise 64-bit.

I use powershell in the administrator mode and recognized that "Get-Disk" -command missing.

Why?

I also use "show-command" and there wasn't  "Get-Disk" command.

Comment: Get-Disk shows up in "Windows Server 2012"

Answer (score 0):

Get-Disk shows up in "Windows Server 2012"

```
Import-Module Storage

Get-Disk
```